# Error CS1061 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no accessible extension method 'Date'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I have this code.

```
public class PagingDto
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionFilter : PagingDto
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
}
```

**GetAllTransactions**

```
public IQueryable<Transaction> GetAllTransactions(TransactionFilter filter)
{
    var transactions = _context.Transactions
        .Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date >= filter.StartDate && x.CreatedDate.Date <= filter.EndDate)
        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery) || x.Customer.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
    || x.Payment.Status.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
    || x.Payment.TransactionReference.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
    || x.Payment.MethodOfPayment.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
    || x.Payment.Amount.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchQuery))
        .Include(b => b.Payment)
        .Include(b => b.Customer)
        .OrderByDescending(transaction => transaction.CreatedDate);
    return transactions;
}
```

I want to Query all transactions that falls between StartDate and EndDate using CreatedDate.

But I got thus error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no accessible extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Then **Date** is highlighted in

```
.Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date >= filter.StartDate && x.CreatedDate.Date <= filter.EndDate)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please point to a specific line in the code that gives an error?

Comment: A `DateTime?` variable **might not have a value** - check out [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: @VladDX -  Date is highlighted in     .Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date >= filter.StartDate && x.CreatedDate.Date <= filter.EndDate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime?` is an equivalent of `Nullable<DateTime>`.

`Nullable<T>` doesn't have a property `.Date`.

You should write:

```
x.CreatedDate.Value.Date
```

But you should keep in mind that `x.CreatedDate` can be `null` in the runtime. In that case, you`ll get a` NullReferenceExpection`.

So, your logic should support such a case and should contain additional checks not to call `x.CreatedDate.Value.Date` when `x.CreatedDate` is `null`.

> Useful links:
>
> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: Is there a way to format the to DD-MMM-YY or DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: @Ayobamilaye, not sure what your question means. Can you provide a bit more context?